# Explain part of proof: If $f$ is infinitely differentiable then $f$ coincides with a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

Simple question, I am following the proof of Theorem 38.5 of Elementary Analysis by Kenneth A. Ross (2nd edition) page 353,

Theorem: Let $f(x)$ be $C^\infty$ on $(a,b)$ such that for every point $x$ in the 
interval there exists an integer $N_x$ for which $f^{(N_x)}(x)=0$; then $f(x)$ 
is a polynomial.

and I could not understand a simple step in the proof. The whole proof has been asked before such as [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial).

Proof:
To start, it suffices to show that $f$ agrees with a polynomial on every closed subinterval [c,d] of (a,b). We show that every nondegenerate closed
subinterval I of [c, d] contains an open subinterval J on which f is a
polynomial. For each $k≥0$, we let $$E_{k} =\{x∈I:f^{(k)}(x)=0\}$$ Then, by hypothesis $I = \cup_{k≥0} E_k$, and by the continuity of the function $f$ and all of its derivatives, each $E_k$ is closed.

My question is why is each $E_k$ closed? How does continuity of $f$ and all of its derivatives imply that each $E_k$ closed? It will be much appreciated if you could please give me a good explanation even if it is trivial or clear as mentioned a lot [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f^{(k)}$ is a continuous function.  If $x_n$ is a sequence converging to $x$ and $f^{(k)}(x_n)= 0$ for all $n$, then $f^{(k)}(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f^{(k)}(x_n) = 0$.